# how can I replace a certain item in a list within python?

Tags: python

For example, I have to write a function called 'replace' that consumes a list, an item 'old', and an item 'new' and mutates the list by replacing old by new. If the item old is not in the list, the list should not change but all items in the input are distinct

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Share your tries, identify a specific problem to reach that, then ask about. You won't step up if you don't train

Answer (score 0):

Replaces the index of the old item by a new item

```py
lst[lst.index(old)] = new
```

```
lst - your list

old - old element

new - new element
```

Oh also check out this link: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+lists&oq=python+lists&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l3.1754j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
lst = [1, 5, 3, 9, 8]

def replace(lst, old, new):
    if old in lst:
        if new not in lst:
            lst[lst.index(old)] = new

            return lst
```

Firstly, it checks to see if the old value actually is in the list. If it is, then it checks if the new value is **not** in the list.

Assuming, these are true, it then changes the old value to the new value with the line: `lst[lst.index(old)] = new`.

Finally, it returns the new list with the modified value!

Comment: Thank you so much!! My classmate and I were stuck on this question for quite some time.

Comment: No problem. Hope it helped!